# Bokeh - Add title to DataTable

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

In Bokeh , Python:

[The DataTable is one of the only widget not to have a `title` attribute.](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html#data-table)

What is the correct pythonic way of adding a title to a DataTable ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best options is to add a `Div` above the `DataTable` in a `column` with the title text you want in the `Div`